# Summation symbol different for two similar cases

Tags: math-mode

Why in the above formula the subscript and superscript for summation symbol is different from the below one?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{R}^{2}=1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}{(\mu_{a}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{RMSE}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

please note that it is numbered formula

Comment: The two components of fractions are set in text-mode math (to save space). If you insist you can use `\frac{\displaystyle \sum ... }{ ...}`

Answer (score 2):

As explain @daleif in his comment,  nominators and denominators in fractions are set in text-mode math.  This can be changed by `\displaystyle` and `\limits`:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}^{2}=1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}{(\mu_{a}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}^{2}=1-\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}{(\mu_{a}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R}^{2}=1-\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}{(\mu_{a}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{RMSE}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-p_{i})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]